# debugging c# in the command line

Tags: c#, debugging, command-line, mono

Just for fun, how close can we get to debug an application in C# using only the command-line out-of-the-box? No other software, just the command-line. That is, for instance, is there a way to peek at the values of variables, interact with output, etc. like the VS debugger does?

**EDIT:** And just for completeness' sake, here is the mono equivalent: http://mono-project.com/Guide:Debugger, although it doesn't seem to be very stable.

Thanks.

Comment: You means, something like gdb for managed code?

Comment: @Martinho. Yes, something like that. Look at driis' answer, and a screenshot here: http://www.insidepro.com/kk/258/258_11.jpg, that's quite awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [CLR debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxbks7z.aspx), which is part of the framework installation; and does not depend on VS.

An alternative (and more appropiate for your question) is [MDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx), which is a command line debugger for managed code.

Comment: Very interesting! Probably MDbg is what I'm looking for... I'll give it a shot.

Comment: MDbg may have been a valuable option back in 2009 but it is definitely outdated now. @driis (if you are still there) are there any viable alternatives to MDbg in 2022 for C# code running on .NET 6?

Answer (score 1):

There are command line debuggers that come with [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217084226/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) like [CDB](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6469/Debug-Tutorial-Part-1-Beginning-Debugging-Using-CD)
. For managed applications you will also need the [SOS module](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024041713/http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Darin. I'm only after what can be done with the tools that come with VS, no additional downloads.